# Foursquare venues/explore returning empty data set

Tags: api, foursquare

Foursquare's venue/explore endpoint has been returning an empty data set for me all day. It has been working prior. Any ideas? I haven't seen any reports of any similar problems from other users. Both are popular coordinates in NY / SF.

Requests:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=XXXX&v=20121121

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=37%2E785834,-122%2E406417&oauth_token=XXXX&v=20121121
```

Current Return Snippets:

```
There aren't a lot of results near you. Try something more general, reset your filters, or expand the search area.

There aren't a lot of check-ins here (yet!). All the more reason to go explore!
```

Comment: Did you hit their request quota/limits? I don't know the first thing about the Foursquare API but if things worked for you previously and then suddenly ceased to, that would be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: Yup, pretty sure, the client-id is a test account and I have been the only one using it. Also, returning a 200 OK.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you are hitting rate limits. results should be showing up for those coordinates. Are you still seeing this issue? I am not able to reproduce this.

Comment: I am having the same problem. The method works previously, but now returns empty data.

Comment: This issue has been resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed, all queries should be working now.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the case, now. Thanks!