# Foursquare Explore API endpoint seems to be broken

Tags: foursquare

I have been using Foursquare Explore API endpoint since I have started developing an application. But recently it seems to be broken. It keeps on giving me following response

**warning: {
text: "There aren't a lot of results near you. Try something more general, reset your filters, or expand the search area."
}**

I am trying to get the response from the following HTTP URL - 
**https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74&v=20121124**

(adding my credentials to the above URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue has been noticed couple days ago on this page
[Foursquare venues/explore returning empty data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488905/foursquare-venues-explore-returning-empty-data-set)

I'd really like foursquare to keep us informed, because we can't rely on their API if no information about what's going on is provided :(

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed, all queries should be working now. Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention.